# How can I combine class with class that has condition? vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component is like this :

```
<template>
    <a class="btn btn-block" :class="[response == 'responseFound' ? ' btn-yellow' : ' btn-default']">
    ...
    </a>
 </template>
```

It works

But, I want to combine it to be one class

I try like this :

```
<template>
    <a :class="'btn' [response == 'responseFound' ? ' btn-yellow' : ' btn-default'] ' btn-block'">
    ...
    </a>
 </template>
```

But it does not work

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why do you want to combine them? This is the correct way of doing it. Also it doesn't need to be an array since you only have one class you're setting.

Comment: Write code like in javascript : `:class="'btn ' + ((response == 'responseFound') ? 'btn-yellow' : 'btn-default') + ' btn-block'">`

Comment: Yup why do you want to combine, vue does that for you. The first process you followed is the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything inside :class or v-bind:class is an expression. So:

```
<template>
    <a :class="'btn' + ( response == 'responseFound' ? ' btn-yellow' : ' btn-default') + ' btn-block'">
    ...
    </a>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine different binding styles in an array:

```
<a :class="'btn btn-block', [response == 'responseFound' ? ' btn-yellow' : ' btn-default']">
```