# How can I add 2 condition in one class vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component is like this :

```
<template>
    <a :class="'btn ' + [respond == 'responseFound' ? ' btn-yellow' : ' btn-default', type == 1 ? ' btn-block' : ' btn-xs center-block']">
       ...
    </a>
</template>
```

I try like that, but it does not work?

Comment: Bro you keep asking the same question with different titles. I think this is the third one you are asking. Why not bundle all you doubts in a neat list provide code, good explanation and would be better if provided with a jsfiddle .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I combine class with class that has condition? vue.js 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759229/how-can-i-combine-class-with-class-that-has-condition-vue-js-2)

Comment: It's diffrent. You must read corectly. This is two condition

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `:class="[array, of, classes]"` syntax:

```
<a :class="['btn', (respond === 'responseFound' ? 'btn-yellow' : 'btn-default'), (type === 1 ? 'btn-block' : 'btn-xs center-block')]">
```

As a bonus you don't have to worry about adding the leading spaces, Vue will handle it.

Comment: What if i require two class to display, this method seems to be able to display one class only

Comment: @CodeGuru the example does allow multiple classes out of a condition, notice the `(type === 1 ? 'btn-block' : 'btn-xs center-block')` portion

Answer (score 9):

Just to keep things clean in view/template/markup, move your conditions to computed properties:

```
<template>
  <a :class="['btn', getRespondClass, getTypeClass]">
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        respond: '',
        type: ''
      }
    },
    computed: {
      getRespondClass () {
        return this.respond === 'responseFound' ? 'btn-yellow' : 'btn-default'
      },
      getTypeClass () {
        return this.type === 1 ? 'btn-block' : 'btn-xs center-block'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the current showed answer says how you can add multiple classes on 1 condition. But if you want to have multiple conditions for your class added you can simply just do it like this:

```
:class="{'classname': condition_one && condition_two}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this:

```
:class="[ condition1 | condition2 ? 'className' : '']"
```

This checks for either of the conditions to be true. If you want to check for both replace `|` with `&&`. But if you have nothing in the `else` class, I think @Marnix's answer is cleaner.